# Laser IEnumerator not working in Unity. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Code is not working for some weird reason. It's not making any errors, but not shooting anything and the debug log wasn't working either.

```
void Start()
{
    LaserRoutine();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
IEnumerator LaserRoutine()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                SpawnLaser();
            }
            Debug.Log("Spawned");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    }
}
void SpawnLaser()
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    Instantiate(projectile,pos,transform.rotation);
}
```

Comment: You need to use `StartCoroutine(LaserRoutine());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an enumerator to do something, you must iterate it. In Unity this can be done with  `StartCoroutine`

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(LaserRoutine());
}
```

See [WaitForSeconds example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html).

The reason is that an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators) (a method with `yield return`) is just a setup waiting to be iterated. It does not do anything by itself.